# hyperlink eval navigateurl complete path not required

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, navigateurl

In database I have a column for website name. This website I am displaying inside a listview in a hyperlink field. I want that when user click on the link it should redirect to the website in new tab but right now when clicking the folder structure is prefixing before the website name. Here is the code for Hyperlink. What should I do to remove the prefix from website name. The text of website is displaying fine. Please advice:

```html
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplWebsite" runat="server" style="text-decoration: underline;" Text='<%# Eval("Website")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website")%>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```